# Syntax Error when including a module that imports another module

Tags: python, import, path

I am trying to create smaller files than can themselves be run standalone in order to test them. One of my files reads data from a csv and the test is the plot the data. I am now creating a module that makes a moving average of the data, the test will be to read in the data (using the other module) and then run itself on the data and plot it. Each file is stored in its own directory (the read file module is stored in _ReadBand)

The issue seems to be with the `%matplotlib inline` command that i am using (i am working in ipython) that is only found in the test area

Here is my Read CSV file

```
##
# Read sensor band data
# Creates Timestamps from RTC ticks
##

import pandas as pd

from ticksConversion import ticks_to_time #converts difference in rtc to float of seconds

def read_sensor(folder_path, file_path):

    ##This function takes csv of raw data from sensor
    ##and returns the invidual signals as a well as a timestamp made from the real time clock

    #Create full path
    data_path = folder_path + file_path

    #Read CSV
    sensor_data = pd.read_csv(data_path, header=0, names=['time', 'band_rtc', 'ps1', 'ps2', 'ps3'])

    #Extract sensor signals and rtc into lists
    sensorData = [list(sensor_data.ps1), list(sensor_data.ps2), list(sensor_data.ps3)]

    #Create Timestamps based on RTC
    sensorTimestamp = [0] #first timestamp value
    secondsElapsed = 0 #running total of seconds for timestamps
    for indx, val in enumerate(sensor_data.band_rtc):
        if( indx == 0):
            continue #If first rtc value simply continue, this data already has timestamp zero

        secondsElapsed += ticks_to_time(sensor_data.band_rtc[indx-1], sensor_data.band_rtc[indx]) #convert rtc elapsed to seconds and add to total

        sensorTimestamp.append(secondsElapsed) #add timestamp for this data point

    return sensorTimestamp, sensorData

#Test code
if __name__ == "__main__":

    #matplotlib - 2D plotting library
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib as mpl
    %matplotlib inline

    #Test Data Path
    folder_path = './'
    file_path = 'testRead.csv'

    #Test Fuunction
    sensorTimestamp, sensorData = read_sensor(folder_path, file_path)

    #Plot Data
    for indx, data in enumerate(sensorData):
        plt.figure(figsize=(20,3))
        plt.plot(sensorTimestamp, sensorData[indx], label='data from LED %i' %indx)
        plt.title('Raw Reading from Band')
        plt.legend(loc='best')
        plt.show()
```

This is my moving average file:

```
##
# Moving average Filter
##

def loop_rolling_mean(numRolls, dataset, window):

    ## Moving average with specificed window sized moved over data specified number of times
    ## Input:
    # dataset - data to average
    # numRolls - number of times to do a moving average
    # window - window size for average, must be odd for unshifted data
    ##Output
    # rolledMean - averaged data

    rolledMean = Series(dataset) # Copy data over and cast to pandas series

    for x in range(0,numRolls): #iterate how many times that you want to do run the window
        rolledMean = pd.rolling_mean(rolledMean, window, min_periods=1, center=True)

    return rolledMean ## the dataset that had the rolling mean going forward x number of times

def loop_rolling_mean_with_reverse(numRolls, dataset, window):

    ##roll over data set forward and backward to get rid of offset
    ## Input:
    # dataset - data to average
    # numRolls - number of rolls (forward and backward), must be even for unshifted data
    # window - window size for average
    ##Output
    # rolledMean - averaged data

    #Error Checking
    if(numRolls%2 != 0):
        return "Number of rolls must be even for un-shifted data"

    ## Now going to do the alternating rolling

    rolledMean = Series(dataset) # Copy data over and cast to pandas series

    for x in range(0, int(numRolls/2)):
        forwardRoll = pd.rolling_mean(rolledMean, window, min_periods=1) #roll data in forward direction
        reversdData = forwardRoll.reindex(index=forwardRoll.index[::-1]) #reverse data
        reverseRoll = pd.rolling_mean(reversdData, window, min_periods=1) #roll over reversed data
        rolledMean = reverseRoll.reindex(index=reverseRoll.index[::-1]) #reverse data again so its in correct order

    return rolledMean

#Test code
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # import readBand
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, '../_ReadBand')
    import readBand

    matplotlib - 2D plotting library
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib as mpl
    %matplotlib inline

    #Set number of rolls and Window
    numRolls = 2
    windowSize = 3

    rolledSensorData = []
    for indx, val in enumerate(sensorData):
        rolledSensorData.append(loop_rolling_mean(numRolls, sensorData[indx], windowSize))

    #Plot Data
    for indx, val in enumerate(rolledSensorData):
        plt.figure(figsize=(20,3))
        plt.plot(sens_data.timestamp, sensorData[indx], label='raw data')
        plt.plot(sensor_data.timestamp, rolledSensorData[indx], label='Moving Avg forward')
        plt.title('LED %i' %indx)
        #plt.axis([8,22, 7000, 8600])
        plt.legend(loc='best')
        plt.show()

    for indx, val in enumerate(rolledSensorData):
        print len(rolledSensorData[indx])
```

And this is the error i receive, as you can see it refers to the test area in readBand.py

```
  File "../_ReadBand\readBand.py", line 43
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I dont even think this part of the code should be running since its being imported and not the main

Comment: i *think* the `%` is part of the ipython console. You dont need it in the program. Just remove it and try..

Comment: But i don't get the same error when running and testing the readBand module by itself. Regardless i removed it from readBand and now it still has a syntax error but the carrot that points to the 'e' in "inline" from readBand instead of the %

Comment: @user3123955: What exactly do you mean by "running and testing the readBand module by itself"? Are you doing `readBand.py`? Or `python -m  readband`? Or `%run readband.py` from inside IPython? Or something different?

Comment: Meanwhile, you've posted a few hundred lines of code from two modules, and none of the code from the one that actually has the problem. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to strip down your code to something people can read, understand, and debug for you.

Comment: @abarnert by "running and testing readBand module by itself" i mean that i run the readBand ipython notebook which runs the `if __name__ == main:` block, i then copy the entire notebook to a python file called readBand.py so i can import it into my other ipython notebook which is the moving average one. I am under the presumption that by including the readBand.py in this ipython notebook i can run the read_sensor function without the `if __name__ == main:` block executing.

I dont know what you mean by not posting the code that causes the problem. The issue is between these two files.

Comment: OK, of course using IPython magic commands works in IPython notebooks that you run directly in IPython. But they're not valid Python code, so they don't work in any other context.

Comment: As for not posting the code that has the problem… you say the error is in `readBand.py`, but you've shown us the code for something named "Read CSV" and something named "Moving Average", and neither of those sounds like a file you'd call `readBand.py`, and the only `%` character I see anywhere in a code block on the screen is in `if(numRolls%2 != 0):`, which is obviously not relevant here. But meanwhile, do you not understand that MCVE link, or do you just not want to provide a minimal example so people can actually help you?

Comment: My apologies the Read CSV file was copied and saved as readBand.py. I see, when i import the .py it sees the directive and cannot recognize it. Thanks